# A good way in .NET Winforms to have user entered time frame?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Does anyone know of a good way to have a user enter an amount of time (hours and minutes) using winforms controls? At the moment I have two numeric up downs, one for time and one for minutes that I then parse to create a timespan. The only other idea I have is a text box that a user can enter a "00:00" time in, and validate the input. Both of these ways seem a bit bad (in UI terms) though.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).  This will allow you to have an input box with a format based on the mask you choose (e.g. `__:__`).  This would be useful in the event that a time amount may be above 24 hours (which a DateTimePicker control wouldn't allow you to enter).

Comment: Any example code?

Answer (score 10):

Entering times is never an easy thing to represent in a UI. Take a look at two things in Windows where times are entered:

1. Adding a new scheduled task:
   [image: Adding a new scheduled task]
2. Changing the system time:
   [image: Changing the system time]

Both of these use a custom text box type control where you can type a value, or use the up/down control to change the value. Those are probably the best compromise.

You can achieve this yourself by using the built-in [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) control, and then changing the [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) property to match the format you want (ie. HH:mm for you example of hours and minutes). The [ShowUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showupdown(v=VS.90).aspx) property can also be used to optionally display the spin button control as in the pictures above.

Comment: pretty version of my answer XD

Comment: I'm not sure if this was always the case, but in my case I also needed to set the `Format` property to `Custom` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I normally just use the DateTimePicker control. I select the custom format option and set it to HH:mm and set the ShowUpDown option to true.

Another thing that comes to my mind is to stablish (lets say) minute as your time unit then ask the user for a specific quantity in a textbox.... and add labels telling to enter amount of time in minutes....

Answer (score 0):

Use the clock method `00:00` and put little arrow buttons above and below the hours and minutes section so they can click to increment/decrement, plus they can type it in, just like the vote button on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned mainly about usability, and wanting to create a timespan, why not just use  2 drop down lists? 1 for hours, 1 for minutes.  Very straightforward and little room for error from the user

Comment: A drop down list with 60 items in it is not very usable.

Comment: well it could have 15 minute intervals, with a link button saying something like "more minutes?", but still, its an ordered list, so I would argue that its fine